# How to update Parent form from a Modal

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal form that updates a client's address once the "save" button is clicked. I want to use a AJAX call to update the Model's data once the modal form is closed. It would then redirect back to the parent form from which the modal form was called (Index.cshtml). The AJAX call is successfully retrieving the updated modal form's data via the textboxes but it always throws an error.

TL;DR: Want to close a modal form, redirect to parent form and update the text displayed there.

Please see below for my code snippets:

**Controller**

```
[ValidateInput(false), HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateClientDetails(Client newClientDetails)
{
    _clientService.UpdateClient(newClientDetails);

    return Json(newClientDetails);
}
```

---

```
$('.btn-update-client').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#updateClientModal .modal-content').load('/client/UpdateClientDetails/' + id);
        $('#updateClientModal').modal('show');
});
```

**View (Index.cshtml)**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <label>Client Id: <span id="ClientId">@id</span></label>
    <address>
        <span id="Address1">@client.Address1</span>, <span id="Address2">@client.Address2</span><br>
        <span id="City">@client.City</span>, <span id="Province">@client.Province</span><br>
        <span id="PostalCode">@client.PostalCode</span><br>
        <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> <span id="PhoneNumber">@client.PhoneNumber</span>
    </address>
    <div><button value="@id" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-update-client">Change</button></div>
</div>
```

__

**Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_clientService.GetClientList());
}
```

**Modal Form**

```
@model Client
@using ProductManager.Models

<div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">@Model.Name - ID: @Model.Id</h4>
</div>
@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    attributes.Add("class", "form-horizontal");
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateClientDetails", "Client", FormMethod.Post, attributes))
{
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientAddress1" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Address 1</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientAddress1" name="Address1" value="@Model.Address1">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientAddress2" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Address 2</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientAddress2" name="Address2" value="@Model.Address2">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientCity" class="col-xs-3 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientCity" name="City" value="@Model.City">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientProvince" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Province</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Province, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProvinceList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "clientProvince" })
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientPostalCode" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Postal Code</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientPostalCode" name="PostalCode" value="@Model.PostalCode">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientPhoneNumber" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone #</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clientPhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" value="@Model.PhoneNumber">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="clientName" name="Name" value="@Model.Name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="clientID" name="Id" value="@Model.Id">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: getModelData(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                $("#Address1").text(data.Address1);
                $("#Address2").text(data.Address2);
                $("#City").text(data.City);
                $("#Province").text(data.Province);
                $("#PostalCode").text(data.PostalCode);
                $("#PhoneNumber").text(data.PhoneNumber);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured!");
            }
        });

        function getModelData() {
            var dataToSubmit = {
                Address1: $("#clientAddress1").val(),
                Address2: $("#clientAddress2").val(),
                City: $("#clientCity").val(),
                Province: $("#clientProvince").val(),
                PostalCode: $("#clientPostalCode").val(),
                PhoneNumber: $("#clientPhoneNumber").val()
            };

            return dataToSubmit;
        }
    });
</script>
```

After clicking the "Save" button on my modal form, it redirects to `http://localhost:6969/Client/UpdateClientDetails/1234` with the following string:

```
{"Address1":"38 Lesmill Rd","Address2":"Suite 1",
 "City":"Toronto","Province":"ON","PostalCode":"M3B 2T5",
 "PhoneNumber":"(416) 445-4504","Id":2827,"Name":"Advisor Centric"}
```

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a modal then you should not have left the original page. What does the modal view look like? What does your `POST /Home/Index` action look like? **View (Starting Form)** is that your index view?

Comment: @Jasen After clicking the "Save" button on my modal form, it redirects to `http://localhost:6969/Client/UpdateClientDetails/1234` with the following string: {"Address1":"38 Lesmill Rd","Address2":"Suite 1","City":"Toronto","Province":"ON","PostalCode":"M3B 2T5","PhoneNumber":"(416) 445-4504","Id":2827,"Name":"Advisor Centric"}

Comment: Since you are doing an AJAX post on your form submit button you must prevent the default form submission (which causes the browser to navigate to the form's `action`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are being redirected when you click the save function, it could be due to a few reasons. The below snippet should solve your problems.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-primary', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: getModelData(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Address1").text(data.Address1);
            $("#Address2").text(data.Address2);
            $("#City").text(data.City);
            $("#Province").text(data.Province);
            $("#PostalCode").text(data.PostalCode);
            $("#PhoneNumber").text(data.PhoneNumber);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error occurred!");
        }
    });

    function getModelData() {
        var dataToSubmit = {
            Address1: $("#clientAddress1").val(),
            Address2: $("#clientAddress2").val(),
            City: $("#clientCity").val(),
            Province: $("#clientProvince").val(),
            PostalCode: $("#clientPostalCode").val(),
            PhoneNumber: $("#clientPhoneNumber").val()
        };
        return dataToSubmit;
    }
});
```

**Changes to snippet explained:**

1. Instead of using the jQuery click method, I have updated this to use the `on` method. This will allow us to attach an event to the `btn-primary` class even if it is loaded after the dom has been rendered.
2. We are now passing in the event object into the method. This allows us to prevent any default behavior that is expected, for example submitting the form traditionally. This is accomplished with the `event.preventDefault()` method.

Comment: Instead of preventing the default click, better is to prevent the "submit" event.

Comment: In this particular case @Jasen, we are preventing the form submission. Given the button is inside of a form, and given the button has a type of submit, when the user clicks on the button, then the default behavior is to submit the form. Therefore, preventing the form submit would be superfluous.